# Adding Time Frame to Online PHP Form for email

Tags: php, forms, email

I have pieced together some PHP code below that creates a nice HTML email from an Ajax form submission, complete with a table. However, I wanted to make it so that an error message will pop up if the time frame entered is in less than a 48 hours. I wanted to know what would be the easiest way to go about changing in the html as well as the php in order to get this to work, or if it's even possible.

HTML Code

```
<input name="Event Date" type="text" required id="Event Date" style="border-radius:5px; height:25px; font-family:'Quicksand', sans-serif; color:#666" title="Event Date" value="MM/DD/YYYY">
```

PHP Code

```
    <?php

 require_once('recaptchalib.php');
 $privatekey = "###########################";
 $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                 $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                 $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                 $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
unset($_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"]);
unset($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
 if (!$resp->is_valid) {
   // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
   die ("The human verification code above WAS NOT entered correctly, please reset the human verification code and try again :-) " .
        "(Error: " . $resp->error . ")");
 } else {
     // Code Below For Handling Form (Send Email)
   function validEmail($email)
{
   $isValid = true;
   $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
   if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
   {
      $isValid = false;
   }
   else
   {
      $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
      $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
      $localLen = strlen($local);
      $domainLen = strlen($domain);
      if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
      {
         // local part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
      {
         // domain part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
      {
         // local part starts or ends with '.'
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
      {
         // local part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
      {
         // character not valid in domain part
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
      {
         // domain part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if
(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',
                 str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
      {
         // character not valid in local part unless
         // local part is quoted
         if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',
             str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
         {
            $isValid = false;
         }
      }
      if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
      {
         // domain not found in DNS
         $isValid = false;
      }
   }
   return $isValid;
}

//Reject hyperlinks
$SpamErrorMessage = "No Websites URLs permitted";
 if (preg_match("/http/i", "$name")) {echo "$SpamErrorMessage"; exit();}
 if (preg_match("/http/i", "$email")) {echo "$SpamErrorMessage"; exit();}
 if (preg_match("/http/i", "$Special Message")) {echo "$SpamErrorMessage"; exit();}

 //48 Hour Time Limit
if ((strptime($_POST['Event Date'], "%m/%d/%Y") - time()) < (48 * 60 * 60)) {echo "Date is under 48 hours notice. Please call for service."; exit();}

//Where is it being sent?
$destination = "handle@domain.com";
$email_from = $_POST['Email'];

if (!validEmail($email_from))
    die("Invalid email address");

$message = "<html>
<body style=\"font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt;\">
Hi,<br>
You have recieved an online order:<br><br>
<table width='600' border='1' cellspacing='3'>";

//Gather posted variables:
foreach($_POST as $keys => $vars){
    if (empty($vars)) continue; #skip if vars is empty
    $message .= "<tr>
    <td bgcolor='#CCCCCC'><b>$keys:</b></td> <td><b><font color='red'>$vars</font></b></td>
    </tr>";
}
$message = str_replace("_"," ", $message);
$message .= "
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

#separating headers properly
$headers = "From: $email_from\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n".
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n".
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n".
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n";

mail($destination,"Online Catering Form Results",$message,$headers);

echo "Thank you for your order!";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Would `if ((strtotime($_POST['Event Date']) - time()) < (48 * 60 * 60)) { $isValid = false; }` be sufficient?

Comment: Hi @MichaelWheeler ! Thanks for the reply! I put it into the code but it keeps rejecting when the 'Event Date' is entered in the format MM/DD/YYYY, even if the date is over 48 hours. 
I used:
`if ((strtotime($_POST['Event Date']) - time()) < (48 * 60 * 60)) {echo "Date is under 48 hours notice. Please call for service."; exit();}`

Comment: Rather than `strtotime()`, try `strptime($_POST['Event Date'], "%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: Thanks @MichaelWheeler ! However, I am still recieving the `echo` message no matter what the date.

Comment: Your best bet would be to do something like `$eventtime = strptime($_POST['Event Date'], "%m/%d/%Y"); var_dump($eventtime); $time = time(); var_dump($time);` and compare the values yourself. Check to see if `strptime()` is acting as expected.

Comment: Hi @MichaelWheeler ! I'm not quite sure what you're instructing me to do. Sorry, novice programmer at best. Do I use that code in place of `(strptime($_POST['Event Date'], "%m/%d/%Y") - time()) < (48 * 60 * 60)) {echo "Date is under 48 hours notice. Please call for service."; exit();}`? Or add it to the code?

Comment: Can you update your original post with the current code, specifically what is near the problematic code?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, and see what Event Time and Time are actually evaluated as.

```
//48 Hour Time Limit
if ((strptime($_POST['Event Date'], "%m/%d/%Y") - time()) < (48 * 60 * 60)) {
    echo "Event Time: " . strptime($_POST['Event Date']) . "\n";
    echo "Time: " . time() . "\n";
    echo "Date is under 48 hours notice. Please call for service."; 
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I am getting Warning: `strptime() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /domain.com/folder/send.php on line 90
Event Time: Time: 1378745498 Date is under 48 hours notice. Please call for service.`

Comment: Oops, change the second line to `echo "Event Time: " . strptime($_POST['Event Date'], '%m/%d/%Y') . '\n'`

Comment: Changed it, now I get - `Event Time: \nTime: 1378786375 Date is under 48 hours notice. Please call for service.` - I entered '09/14/2013' (without quotes) as the event date

Comment: Change the echo line to `echo "Event Time: " . $_POST['Event Date'] . "\n"` Is it possible that your column name is EventDate not Event Date?

Comment: Hi @MichaelWheeler Sorry for the late response, in the Colorado Flood area. I checked and the column is named 'Event Date" - Should I change it? I also input the new code so it reads `//48 Hour Time Limit
if ((strptime($_POST['Event Date'], "%m/%d/%Y") - time()) < (48 * 60 * 60)) {
    echo "Event Time: " . $_POST['Event Date'] . "\n";
    echo "Time: " . time() . "\n";
    echo "Date is under 48 hours notice. Please call for service."; 
    exit();
}` - Now I get `Event Time: Time: 1379115196 Date is under 48 hours notice. Please call for service.` Entered the date as `09/16/2013`

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML for the page? This is contained within a form, correct? And the form method is 'POST', correct?

Comment: The entire form is huge. It's an online order form for a catering company. The HTML in the original post is copied and pasted. And `method="post"`. Would you still like me to post the entire html code (~1000 lines)? Also, thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it! Would it be any easier to make it so that it has to be more than just one day's notice, `x > 1`?